# adb command to get date format for API 21

Tags: android, cmd, sdk, adb

I am writing an automation script for an android application. In the process I came across a condition where I need to get the date format of the device( whether it is dd/mm/yy or mm.dd.yyyy. depending on the local). I am executing an adb command as follows - "*adb shell settings get system date_format*".

However this command only works for API levels 23 and that to it doesn't give the format with proper date formatter.

Eg: On API 23 it gives-
 mm-dd-yyyy when my date format of device(tablet) is set to mm/dd/yyyy ( LOCAL 'EN").

Is there a adb command which will give me the correct date format based on the local for all API versions?